Python3.11 install on Ubuntu 24.04
Why can't the latest stable version (24.04) install python3.11?
Thanks in advance!

What is wrong with python 3.12?

why do you assume you can not?  have a look at https://docs.python.org/3.11/tutorial/venv.html

@Rinzwind It's because the upgrade process seems to break Python so the original poster was not making an assumption. Apparently the issue has even been reported as a bug.

Elastic Beanstalk doesn't run on Python 3.12

@mikewhatever imp was removed in 3.12, breaking a bunch of packages on pypi

As of Ubuntu 24.04's release, Python 3.11 may not be available directly through the official Ubuntu repositories or through Deadsnakes PPA, for instance.
You could, in this case, build Python 3.11 from source.
However, as of my latest check, the Deadsnakes PPA has already updated its support for Ubuntu 24.04 (Noble). So you can just
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.11

https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

From what I gather, add-apt-repository is a Python script and it is Python that trying to upgrade to 24.04 broke on my system. Therefor the above seems to be a paradox in using a Python script to install Python.

@DonP, indeed, add-apt-repository is a Python script. Nevertheless, Ubuntu 24.04 (Noble) already includes Python 3.12, which can run this script. Therefore, you should be able to add the Deadsnakes PPA and install Python 3.11 without any issues.
If the Python installation on your system is broken and you need a fresh reinstall, you have several options: you can build Python from source, reinstall Ubuntu, or explore other methods to repair or reinstall Python.

There did not appear to be any version of Python installed so I had to do a fresh install but since then, lots of 24.04 issues such as it frequently logging itself off and closing all open apps and having unusable audio, it may have been better had I done a fresh install of 23.10 and waited before installing 24.04 as it seems, as late as the release was, more like a beta than a legitimate operating system.

Don't forget to also do sudo apt install python3.11-venv
